# How to convert a property of an object into a string in Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

Is it possible to do something like the following in Objective-c?

```
   NSString *propertyName = NSStringFromSelector(aPerson.personName);
```

`propertyName` would have the string `personName`;

I would like to put this into a category of `NSObject`.

Comment: As you are still typing a lot. why not directly put `NSString *propertyName =@"personName";`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: May be Obj-C runtime? if you want to get all propertynames...posting as answer and will see tomorow how many downvotes..

Comment: @H2CO3 I don't want to be doing what `Annop` is suggesting where by I have to type out the property name into a string.

Comment: @David: Neither by obj-C runtime, nor by direct assignment. Even you want only a particular variablename from a class, then I guess there is no other way. Even Josh's link says Obj-c runtime.

Answer (score 0):

To get all the property names of a class

```
- (NSMutableArray *)getAllPropertyOfClass:(Class)aClass {
    NSMutableArray *mArray=[NSMutableArray new];
    unsigned int outCount;
    objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList([aClass class], &outCount);
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < outCount; i++) {
        objc_property_t property = properties[i];
        const char *propName = property_getName(property);
        if(propName) {
            NSString *propertyName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:propName];
                mArray[mArray.count]=propertyName;
        }
    }
    free(properties);
    return mArray;
}
```

Comment: I've seen this before and it returns a list of strings. I just want once string for the property that I am specifying.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: I simply copied, and edited here, without compile and checking. And i was half-sleep too :p night 1AM, but no excuse. thanks to all for not voting this down.

Comment: If you want just one. And you know **specifically which one**, then why not to assign the variableName in a string directly? Why to program and all to find?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya The whole idea is to get away from having to type out a string. Typing out a string is error prone. If I specify a property that a class does not have, the complier will complain. This is the behaviour that I'm looking for.

Comment: this is what you can do by obj-c runtime. you can get all the properties. but agian you say, you want only one? how will do maintain both the thing? i am not finding any idea.